# how to customize text name on php when using fopen comman

Tags: php, text, alert

how can i customize the text name for the output on my fopen?
i tried using

```
$file = $Aname .'.txt';
```

but it won't output correctly, and also after creating the text file return to the page 
and prompt the user regarding the creation of the file .

```
<?php
$saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
if ($saving == 1){ 
$Aname = $_POST['Aname'];

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$last = $_POST['last']; 
$mob = $_POST['mob']; 
$ext = $_POST['ext']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$add = $_POST['add']; 
$com = $_POST['com']; 
$day = $_POST['day']; 
$text = $_POST['text'];
$date = date("M j, Y "); 

$data = "Date Sent: {$date}\n\nName: {$name} {$last}\nPhone : {$mob} ext: {$ext}\nCompany: {$com}\nAddress : {$add}\nE-mail : {$email}\nDay : {$day}\n\nNote :

\n{$text}\n---------------------------------------\n";

$file = $Aname.'.txt';

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
}
?>
```

and also instead of relocating the user to another page to give this error

```
die("Couldn't write values to file!");
```

just pop up an alert on the page.

Comment: have you considered using `MySQL` to store our information instead of independent flat file

Comment: I don't see why "it" should return anywhere or prompt anyone for anything. The code is about writing data from a request into a file. Nothing more.

Comment: i need the file in text format that's why i'm doing this

Comment: The name you give the file has nothing to do with the content you write into it.

Comment: What exactly does "it won't output correctly" mean?

Comment: it won't create a unique file name instead it create a file named ".txt' without the $Aname value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using file_put_contents(). It replaces the whole fopen, fwrite, fclose headache.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
<?php
$saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
if ($saving == 1){ 
$Aname = $_POST['Aname'];

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$last = $_POST['last']; 
$mob = $_POST['mob']; 
$ext = $_POST['ext']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$add = $_POST['add']; 
$com = $_POST['com']; 
$day = $_POST['day']; 
$text = $_POST['text'];
$date = date("M j, Y "); 

$data = "Date Sent: {$date}\n\nName: {$name} {$last}\nPhone : {$mob} ext: {$ext}\nCompany: {$com}\nAddress : {$add}\nE-mail : {$email}\nDay : {$day}\n\nNote :

\n{$text}\n---------------------------------------\n";

$file = $Aname.'.txt';

file_put_contents ( $file, $data ); 
}
?>
```

Comment: it just create a file named ".txt" instead of creating a file like note.txt from following $Aname . '.txt';

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `$_POST['Aname']` is actually populated (maybe it is coming from `$_GET`?).

Do note by the way that you have opened a rather big security issue here by using unsanitized data to write to disk. Potentially people could overwrite any file on your disk with PHP code and then execute that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute path for the `$filename` parameter of fopen, so replace your following line:

```
$file = $Aname.'.txt';
```

for this one:

```
$file = dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]) . '/' . $Aname.'.txt';
```

The above assumes your web server runs linux, if it's a windows one, you have to escape any backslashes, like `fopen("c:\\my\\document_root\\myfile.txt", "a");`

Comment: still nothing , it still creates the file name ".txt" instead of a file containing the value of $Aname like asdad.text